# How effectively to promote\publicize my web application?

Tags: marketing, website-promotion

I have just finished the development of my application. Now I would like to promote\publicize that (I have no money!). What are techniques most commonly used to do that on the web? And the most efficient?

Comment: Changed to Community Wiki as answers will be subjective (see [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) or inquire on [Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you have questions about this action)

Answer (score 1):

Create a website with appropriate landing pages, designed to market your application. Then the internet really is your oyster.

Collate emails however you can, if you'd have had a large email list of recipients who might have found your application useful that would have been a nice kick start. Concentrate on SEO for the site featuring your web app. Create discussions about it in relevant forums... The list really is endless.

Comment: (1) What about "pass the word"? Is it useful? If so, how can I effectively use also this approach? (2) Can you provide me a link to a list of most popular forums where I can create discussions about my new web site?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'pass the word'? By all means tell all of your online contacts/family/friends. Search for forums relevant to your web application's niche or whose audience might find it useful or interesting, don't plaster it all-over some 'popular' general forums.

Comment: With "pass the word" I mean something like this:  "spread the word (my web site) by telling other people" of my web site.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is one of the greatest bridge that can get you app discovered. It's also the best way to practice the "pass the word" approach that you're talking about because you know who you will be talking to, your friends which will also recommend the app and then the dominos will continue to tip down... :))

Answer (score 0):

when its built send a link to it to relivant blogs if they choose to post about it you could end up with a large amount of targeted traffic which your website would then have to convert into users